# How do I migrate Image Gallery from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7?

Tags: image, drupal, migration, drupal-7, image-gallery

I have a Drupal 6 site that I'm trying to migrate to Drupal 7. However, I have a gallery using the Image and Image Gallery modules.

I know that Image is a dead end from Drupal 6, but the Image nodes can be converted to CCK ImageField fields uning the Field Converter module.

However, a migrationpath for Image Gallery seems to be largely forgotten, or at least I've managed to find almost nothing about it on the web. I think my best option is to roll my own gallery with Views, but I would welcome any tips for bringing my images from the Drupal 6 site.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as [Drupal 6 To 7 Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794331/drupal-6-to-7-migration)

You can use the Migrate module, or even better the Migrate D2D examples which should handle a clean migration for you with the ability of rolling back a migration if any problem occurs. A great way to fine tune a migration, when necessary.

With Migrate, you can migrate your files first, then migrate your Content Types by mapping the various field values. It takes a bit of getting into but once you get the hang of it, you'll love the simplicity & flexibility.